# Kibana: how to convert {{date}} in not UTC format

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, kibana, datetime-format, mustache

Elastic/kibana. I created a alert rule and try to use {{date}} (or {{context.date}}) in my emails.

Right now I am getting the date and time in UTC format like this: 2023-02-01T08:30:59.069Z

How to convert this datetime to another format in local timezone (+2): 2023-02-01 10:30?

I used: `{{dateVar | dateformat="MM/dd/yyyy"}}, {{sysdate}}` and another methods but...

Answer (score 0):

If you are observing your data from Kibana you can update the timezone and time format from:

> Stack management => Advanced Settings

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can format Date

{{#FormatDate}} {{{_source.creationDate}}} ; Brazil/East; DD-MM-YYYY hh:mma {{/FormatDate}}

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/8.9/rule-action-variables.html

TimeZones Reference

Use the TZ column

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Brazil

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).